# Accessing data from JSON object gives TypeError

Tags: python, json

I have JSON data, I'm trying to get the value by passing key but it gives me TypeError

My JSON Data :

```
[
  {
    "hiRes": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SL1003_.jpg",
    "thumb": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41lv4ReBL4L._AC_US40_.jpg",
    "large": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41lv4ReBL4L._AC_.jpg",
    "main": {
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
        355,
        355
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
        450,
        450
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
        425,
        425
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
        466,
        466
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
        522,
        522
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
        569,
        569
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
        679,
        679
      ]
    },
    "variant": "MAIN",
    "lowRes": null
  },
  {
    "hiRes": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SL1005_.jpg",
    "thumb": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41shdN1aAoL._AC_US40_.jpg",
    "large": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41shdN1aAoL._AC_.jpg",
    "main": {
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
        355,
        355
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
        450,
        450
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
        425,
        425
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
        466,
        466
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
        522,
        522
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
        569,
        569
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
        679,
        679
      ]
    },
    "variant": "PT01",
    "lowRes": null
  },
  {
    "hiRes": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SL1005_.jpg",
    "thumb": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41pt8OOHsaL._AC_US40_.jpg",
    "large": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41pt8OOHsaL._AC_.jpg",
    "main": {
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
        355,
        355
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
        450,
        450
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
        425,
        425
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
        466,
        466
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
        522,
        522
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
        569,
        569
      ],
      "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
        679,
        679
      ]
    },
    "variant": "PT02",
    "lowRes": null
  }
]
```

Here there is 3 pairs of JSON for three different images with different format.

I tried to get first pair's "hiRes" value by using

**My code : (What i tried)**

```
 print(data["colorImages"]["initial"][0]["hiRes"])
```

**Error (what i'm getting) :**

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

**What Im expecting :**

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SL1003_.jpg
```

I want to get hiRes value from the JSON data for all 3 pairs.

Comment: `data` is a list-of- dictionaries, not a dictionary itself, and lists can only be indexed with integer values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
jsonData = [{'hiRes': 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SL1003_.jpg', 'thumb': 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41lv4ReBL4L._AC_US40_.jpg', 'large': 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41lv4ReBL4L._AC_.jpg', 'main': {'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SY355_.jpg': [355, 355], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SY450_.jpg': [450, 450], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX425_.jpg': [425, 425], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX466_.jpg': [466, 466], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX522_.jpg': [522, 522], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX569_.jpg': [569, 569], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SX679_.jpg': [679, 679]}, 'variant': 'MAIN', 'lowRes': None}, {'hiRes': 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SL1005_.jpg', 'thumb': 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41shdN1aAoL._AC_US40_.jpg', 'large': 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41shdN1aAoL._AC_.jpg', 'main': {'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SY355_.jpg': [355, 355], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SY450_.jpg': [450, 450], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX425_.jpg': [425, 425], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX466_.jpg': [466, 466], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX522_.jpg': [522, 522], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX569_.jpg': [569, 569], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SX679_.jpg': [679, 679]}, 'variant': 'PT01', 'lowRes': None}, {'hiRes': 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SL1005_.jpg', 'thumb': 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41pt8OOHsaL._AC_US40_.jpg', 'large': 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41pt8OOHsaL._AC_.jpg', 'main': {'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SY355_.jpg': [355, 355], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SY450_.jpg': [450, 450], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX425_.jpg': [425, 425], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX466_.jpg': [466, 466], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX522_.jpg': [522, 522], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX569_.jpg': [569, 569], 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SX679_.jpg': [679, 679]}, 'variant': 'PT02', 'lowRes': None}]
    
for i in range(len(jsonData)):
    print(jsonData[i]["hiRes"])
```

Answer (score 2):

First load your json data as dict

```py
import json

with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Then use list comprehension to loop through the list of dict.

```py
print([d["hiRes"] for d in data])
```

```
['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61mw5BDEYoL._AC_SL1003_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61kOw5lC%2B%2BL._AC_SL1005_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/511019WE7xL._AC_SL1005_.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

First store your json data as multiline string first, or load from .json file.

```
string_json = '''
# your json data here
'''
```

Then convert it to a python object (array in this case) by using json.loads

```
import json
data = json.loads(string_json)
```

Finally, you can use any method to get the value of the high res key by accessing the dictionary using key 'hiRes'. You can use list comprehension or for loop to achieve this.

```
print([v['hiRes'] for v in data])
```

or:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
  print(data[i]['hiRes'])
```